# Did I know + loved or Did I know + love

Tags: tenses

Which of the following sentence is correct and why? Please help.

1. Not until he died, did I know how much I loved him.
2. Not until he died, did I know how much I love him.

Comment: They mean different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends whether you are talking about love as in **"being in love with someone"** or love as in **"admiring someone."**

If the deceased is someone you were in love with, you would use the past because we don't typically declare love for people who are not alive, since they are no longer people. Perhaps it's because we can only love someone who is *capable* of loving back (even if our love is unrequited). This may be why it would sound strange for me to say "I am in love with Bernadette" if Bernadette is not, in fact, alive.

**So for romantic love, the answer is 1.**

However, if the deceased was, for example, a famous musician and you failed to appreciate his musical genius until he died, then you can certainly say that you "love" the musician, presently. You are not talking about romantic love, which requires a living object, but admiration and adoration, which ignores the boundary between the living and the dead.

**So for admiration, the answer is 2.**

*Unless* that musician died, you subsequently adored him and his music, then you learned that he didn't even write his own songs and was a demanding prick in the studio and you therefore stopped admiring him...

**...in which case the answer is 1.**

Comment: +1 for an amusing explanation of why one might fall out of love with a dead musician.